# SQL select with WHERE parameter as string of alternatives

Tags: sql, select, parameters, where-clause

I am a bit of a newbie and have tried to find an answer to this in Google so far but I think I am lacking the correct terminology to find the answer I require.

I have an SQL Select statement that returns a bill of materials from a quote in our quoting package. The quotes all contain individual items that have an individual BOM.

At the moment I am able to return the BOM for ALL items in the quote using a single statement. What I would like to be able to do is give the user the ability to filter certain Items out of the selection.

e.g a quote contains items 1 - 10 (QI.QTE_POS is the Item number). The current query returns the BOM for the whole quote. New functionality would use a string of Item Numbers to only return the BOM for Items in the string (comma separated).

e.g string items = 1,2,6,7,9;

```
SELECT
  QI.QTE_POS AS 'ITEM_NUM',
  QI.DESCR AS 'ITEM',   
  BF.EMARK,
  F.FILL_CODE,
  F.DESCR,
  SUM(BF.FILL_COUNT) AS FILL_COUNT,
  CAST(ROUND(BF.FILL_HEIGHT * 25.4, 2) AS REAL) AS FILL_HEIGHT,
  CAST(ROUND(BF.FILL_WIDTH * 25.4, 2) AS REAL) AS FILL_WIDTH,
  BF.RECTANGULAR,
  S.SUPP_CODE

FROM
  QUOTE_ITEM QI
INNER JOIN BOM_FILL BF ON QI.QUOTE_ITEM_ID = BF.QUOTE_ITEM_ID
INNER JOIN FILL F ON BF.FILL_LIB_ID = F.FILL_LIB_ID AND BF.FILL_ID = F.FILL_ID
INNER JOIN SUPPLIER S ON F.SUPP_LIB_ID = S.SUPP_LIB_ID AND F.SUPP_ID = S.SUPP_ID
INNER JOIN QUOTE Q ON Q.QUOTE_ID = QI.QUOTE_ID

WHERE
  BF.COST_BY_BOM = 'T' AND
  Q.QUOTE_NUM = @QuoteNum AND
  Q.QUOTE_VERS = @QuoteVers AND
  QI.QUOTE_VERS_START <= @QuoteVers AND 
  QI.QUOTE_VERS_STOP >= @QuoteVers AND
  Q.QUOTE_NUM_PREF = @QuotePref AND
  Q.QUOTE_NUM_SUFF = @QuoteSuff

GROUP BY
  QI.DESCR,
  QI.QTE_POS,
  BF.EMARK,
  F.FILL_CODE,
  F.DESCR,
  BF.FILL_HEIGHT,
  BF.FILL_WIDTH,
  BF.RECTANGULAR,
  S.SUPP_CODE

ORDER BY
  F.DESCR,
  QI.DESCR,
  QI.QTE_POS,
  F.FILL_CODE,
  FILL_HEIGHT,
  FILL_WIDTH
```

QI.QTE_POS is the Item Number which I would like to filter by.

To do this manually the pseudo code would be:

```
Where QI.QTE_POS = 1 OR 2 OR 6 or 7 OR 9
```

I not sure how to do this using a parameter though..?

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can offer!

Will

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer to what I was looking for. Could you guys let me know if this is best practice?

if i add the following code to the where statement it seems to return the glass for only the item number whose QTE_POS matches 1 3 or 4

```
QI.QTE_POS IN (1,3,4)
```

Any feedback would be great!

Cheers,

Will